# Correct CPU Frequency in BIOS

Tags: cpu, bios

One of the machines I have is a 10 year old one. I can't discard it due to some sentiment (Mom).

Legacy board: Mercury 810e, 133 MHz FSB
Processor: Pentium III Tualatin 1.2 GHz

**Observation**: I see an entry in the BIOS for the *CPU Frequency* from 6.0 to 11.0. Last value is Safe Mode.

I don't know what value to choose for my CPU. So I'm running that CPU in "Safe Mode".

1. What is the correct value for this CPU?
2. Is Safe Mode really safe to run this CPU?

Comment: Why are you messing with the BIOS at all? If it's been running for 10 years in Safe Mode, sounds like it's pretty safe doesn't it?

Comment: @Mat I did few upgrades to that PC because I wish to keep it for a good time. Threw away old 17" CRT in favor of 22" LCD. Replaced aging SMPS (and to eliminate a bit loud Fan sound). Upgraded IDE HDD, 40 GB to 120 GB. Can't upgrade RAM (max limit 512 MB). Replaced defective LG DVD Combo (can't burn CDs!). So I was looking at BIOS last night. I just wanted to cross check any setting mentioned in the manual but nothing found about it. I can understand what is "Safe Mode" but thinking about other values with only *intention* to keep the CPU running for a long time. Hope now I'm understood?

Comment: In the light of your newest questions, this is an example of a good question.